React Router With Multiple Dynamic Routes for File Explorer
I have a React application that uses React Router. I have a file explorer where users can create folders in folders. I would like to create a url with which a user can directly jump inside that folder. Now, I did not find a solution for React Router with an entire variable url, i.e.:

domain.com/explorer/folder1/folder2/folder3/...

What I could do is limit the depth to 5 for example and do it manually:
{
    path: 'explorer',
    element: <Explorer />,
},
{
    path: 'explorer/:folder1',
    element: <Explorer />,
},
{
    path: 'explorer/:folder1/:folder2',
    element: <Explorer />,
},
{
    path: 'explorer/:folder1/:folder2/:folder3',
    element: <Explorer />,
},
{
    path: 'explorer/:folder1/:folder2/:folder3/:folder4',
    element: <Explorer />,
},
{
    path: 'explorer/:folder1/:folder2/:folder3/:folder4/:folder5',
    element: <Explorer />,
}

This seems very hacky and limits me to a depth of 5. How could I achieve this?

Hardcoding the route depth is one way to go about it, but as you can see it's not very practical. An alternative is to edit the Explorer component to recursively render itself, passing down as props the next level of depth's details.
Basic Example:
const Explorer = ({ depth = 0 }) => {
  const { folderId } = useParams();

  return (
    <>
      <div style={{ paddingLeft: `${depth}rem` }}>
        Folder: {folderId ?? "Root"}
      </div>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/:folderId/*" element={<Explorer depth={depth + 1} />} />
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
};

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/explorer/*",
    element: <Explorer />
  }
]);

Assuming URL path "/explorer/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/folder6/folder7":

